# Can Fist of Unbroken Air target unseen creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

[Way of the Four Elements](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheFourElements) has two similar attacks in its list of Disiplines:

> **Fist of Unbroken Air**:
> You can create a blast of compressed air that strikes like a mighty fist. As an action, you can spend 2 ki points and choose a creature within 30 feet of you. That creature must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed save, the creature takes 3d10 bludgeoning damage, plus an extra 1d10 bludgeoning damage for each additional ki point you spend, and you can push the creature up to 20 feet away from you and knock it prone. On a successful save, the creature takes half as much damage, and you don’t push it or knock it prone.

and

> **Water Whip**:
> You can spend 2 ki points as an action to create a whip of water that shoves and pulls a creature to unbalance it. A creature that you can see that is within 30 feet of you must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature takes 3d10 bludgeoning damage, plus an extra 1d10 bludgeoning damage for each additional ki point you spend, and you can either knock it prone or pull it up to 25 feet closer to you. On a successful save, the creature takes half as much damage, and you don’t pull it or knock it prone.

There are some minor mechanical differences, but otherwise they are almost the same. Except for one apparently critical difference. *Fist of Unbroken Air* targets *"a creature within 30 feet of you"*, while *Water Whip* targets *"a creature that you can see that is within 30 feet of you"*.

I'm ignoring that *Fist…* says *"choose"* while *…Whip* does not; I assume that the monk still chooses the target in the latter case, in spite of the difference in wording.

The difference that I'm asking about is that *…Whip* specifically says *"that you can see"*, while no such restriction is given for *Fist…*. Taking this literally, it seems that *Fist of Unbroken Air* can be used to attack targets that you can't see, whether because they are invisible, you are blinded, it is dark, or for whatever reason you simply don't want to look at them (e.g. [Medusa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/medusa)), and that such attacks don't suffer the usual disadvantage penalty, because there's not actually an attack roll, just a saving roll.

Is that really how that Discipline is intended to work? Or is that simply an oversight in the authoring of the text?

If the former, are there other examples in the rules of attacks where simply by omitting the phrase *"that you can see"*, the attack can be used against unseen targets and yet does not suffer the usual disadvantage against targets one can't see?

Comment: I think the linked duplicate should answer your question. Let us know.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: I don't think either your original proposal or the one linked above completely answer the question, but they are close enough. They both address the essential aspect, and I can infer from that that yes, this is a way to attack an unseen creature without suffering any disadvantage or other penalties.